# Meteor: Easiest way to get longitude and latitude

Tags: meteor, geolocation, ip-geolocation

I finally got a reactive map setup, and I can save markers in a collection.

Now I want to get a users longitude and laditude

**I want to find it using their IP address**

Comment: Awesome this works great! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use atmosphere.js package ([Geolocation](https://atmospherejs.com/mdg/geolocation))`mdg:geolocation` in you application.

Add the above geolocation package in your meteor application using `meteor add mdg:geolocation` in your meteor console. Include the package in you package [using](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_versions) `api.use();` . Then you can use the api call `Geolocation.latLng()` to get the latitude and longitude.

Comment: This returns null **without the api.use**. Where do I use the api.use()?

Comment: inside your package.js file.

Comment: Like this: 
api.use("mdg:geolocation", ["client","server"]);

Comment: Ah I figured out that you need to use it in a helper! Thank you, and by the way, it worked without api.use